Travelling outside Australia as a permanent resident with an expired passport
I got my permanent residency in Australia last year. I am Nepalese citizen.
I was planning to travel to nepal and booked a flight with Air India. But I just noticed today that my passport expired last month. Can i still leave Australia with an expired passport? I know that as a Nepalese citizen, I don't need to have a passport to travel inside India.

The airline may require you to have a valid passport to board the plane.
